# flex 4 image dimensions

Tags: actionscript-3, image, flex4, dimensions

I am trying to get the image dimensions to center in the dynamic sprite object but I am getting 0 in the height and widh property. Can some one please help me to get the image dimensions? I tried by using various properties of image control but I am getting the dimensions. Please see code below and the values in the inline comments

mxml code:

```
<mx:Image id = "imgActive" visible="false" />
```

event handler:

```
  private function addImageHandler(e:MyCustomeEve){
            imgActive.source = e.imageUrl; 
            imgActive.visible = true;

            GAME_STATUS = "ITEM_SELECTED";
            trace(imgActive.width,
                imgActive.height, // 0
                imgActive.contentHeight, // 0
                imgActive.contentWidth, // NaN
                imgActive.content.width, // error because imgActive.content is null
                imgActive.content.height  // error because imgActive.contentis null);
            imgActive.cacheAsBitmap = true;
}
```

Comment: What is the event you are listening to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the source of the image you'll have to wait for it to load the content. Add an event listener like `imgActive.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImgActiveComplete);`

When the image is loaded, the onImgActiveComplete handler function will be called and you can then get the dimensions of the image for example by using imgActive.content.width and imgAcive.content.height respectively.

Hope this helps,

Blaze

Comment: Thanks Blaze for the idea. That has lead to another problem. Can you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724739/flex-4-wait-for-load-complete-without-freezing

Comment: I was just looking at this :D