# flex 4 - wait for load complete without freezing

Tags: image, flex4

I was wondering if it is possible to implement any logic to wiat for the image to complete load without freezing.

For the sake of my app, I created a class which takes image url in constructor and loads the mx.controls.Image using the "load()" function.

See the class below

```
package com
{
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.*;
//import flash.net.URLRequest;

import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.controls.Image;
//import mx.utils.OnDemandEventDispatcher;

public class SpriteImage extends Sprite
{
    //Pass the source path or url here.
    private var imageUrl:String;
    private var ready:int = -1;
    private var img:Image;

    public function SpriteImage(imgUrl:String)
    {
        //imageUrl = imgUrl;
        loadImage(imgUrl);
    }
    private function loadImage(imgUrl:String):void
    {

        img = new Image();
        img.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onCompleteHandler);
        img.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onErrorHandler);     
        //img.source = imgUrl;
        img.load(imgUrl);

    }

    private function onCompleteHandler(e:Event):void{

        img.x = -(img.width/2);
        img.y = -(img.height/2);
        this.addChild(img);
        ready = 1;
    }

    private function onErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
        ready = 0;
        //Alert.show("Can't load :" + e.toString());
    }

    public function prepare():Boolean{

        while(ready == -1){
            trace(0);
        }           
        return ready;
    }
}

}
```

Now, I use this class from main app like this

```
var img:SpriteImage = new SpriteImage(e.imageUrl);
img.prepare(); // just waits till image is loaded but freezes
var obj:DisplayObject = img;
```

Now the problem is that the app never comes out of the prepare() method. It freezes the browser and I have to kill the plugin process to unfreez the app.

The main criteria here is that I need to wait for the image to complete loading so that I can access the image in the next steps. How can I do this.? Please help

Comment: Anton's answer is in the right direction.  One thing Flash got right is enforcing asynchronous external calls, which means one **must** use callbacks/event listeners in order for the program to execute properly, and that's what ensures (or at least encourages the programmer to implement in such a way) that the UI will be responsive.  Personally, I found Doug Crockford's lecture on [Loopage](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6yn9HqtBW_U) to be enlightening as to why this is actually a good thing, and not just an arbitrarily conceived pattern there to annoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you're creating the freeze yourself with that **while(ready == -1)** Why don't you just disable the ability for a user to go further in your "steps" until the image is loaded?

You don't have to synchronously wait for the image to load the way you do now. Once the image is loaded, you'll get the notification by the complete event that its loader dispatches. Then you can enable whatever depends on that image being loaded.

One straight forward way is to bind the **enabled** property of the navigation controls in your application to a boolean property. For example in your SpriteImage add

```
[Bindable] public var isImageLoaded:Boolean = false;
```

and set it to true once the onCompleteHandler is called. You can bind to that property's value. Another way is to dispatch an event from your class to notify others that the image is loaded and that something can happen :]

Blaze

Comment: Your code crashed my flash builder 2 times.. please rethink your way of doing what you're trying to do considering my reply.

Comment: Thanks for reply Blaze. If you see the handlers (complete/ioerror), I am changing the value on error/complete, expecting the while loop condition fails in fraction of seconds but it seems like it wont. May be the limitation of the flash/flex itself. (cont...)

Comment: Let me give you overview what I am trying to achieve. This app is basically a game (similar to cityville), here I have a menu to show all the items which player can buy. The momenent player chooses the item (step 1) of his wish the menu is closed (step 2) and the selected item's (say house, tree) image is moved along with the mouse (step 3) and the moment player drops (step 4, clicked on the playable area) it is added to the stage (step 5).

Comment: I am trying to load the image dynamically between steps 1 & 2 using the code below


     var img:SpriteImage = new SpriteImage(e.imageUrl);
     img.prepare(); // just waits till image is loaded but freezes
     var obj:DisplayObject = img;


and the mouse move event follows immediatly (step 3), now how can I stop the mouse event? is there any way to halt the user actions? how?

Comment: Sorry for those crashes. I kill "plugin-container.exe" process to avoid browser/app flash builder crashes

Answer (score 0):

A `ProgressBar` could spice up your UI in a way that it's not freezing when you load the image.

Have a look at the [Adobe docs for the ProgressBar control](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d8c.html). The paragraph titled **Creating a ProgressBar control** has an example which shows how to display a `ProgressBar` while the image is being loaded.